# Azure Log Analytics query for api calls by user

Tags: azure, api, azure-api-management, azure-log-analytics

I've my Azure APIM setup, I want to query the logs for users who made a call to API. I've integrated Azure AD as well.

I want to know how can I retrieve information for the users that have signed in and made calls to a particular API in the developer portal. can I do that?

Something like...
this user with username (or maybe ID) has made calls to this API, this number of times.

is this achievable?

Answer (score 0):

You may query by the API Management UserId

```
requests
| summarize count() by user_AuthenticatedId
```

This refers to the user of the subscription key, which was used to make the API call - so it has the same granularity as

```
requests
| extend Subscription_Name = tostring(customDimensions.["Subscription Name"])
| summarize count() by Subscription_Name
```

From within **Log Analytics** / **App Insights** you have no further details on the user making the API call itself. I usually use a Jupyter notebook to query Log Analytics over API and then query API Management `users` to enrich this information.

But initially you may also just download the query result into a spreadsheet, extract userId and Name from API Management with e.g. Azure PowerShell and use some spreadsheet magic to merge the information.